Find some subset of $C[a,b]$ which is open for $\|~\|_\infty$ but not for $\|~\|_1$

Let $C[a,b]$ be the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$. For
every $x,y\in C[a,b]$, set $$d(x,y)=\sup\limits_{t\in
 [a,b]}|x(t)-y(t)|$$ $$\rho (x,y)=\int\limits_{a}^{b} |x(t)-y(t)|dt$$
Admit that $C[a,b]$ together with $d,\rho$ are metric spaces.
a) Prove
that the topology $\tau _1$ induced by $d$ is stronger than
the topology $\tau _2$  induced by $\rho$ (which is
$\tau_1\supseteq\tau_2$) . From here, prove that $$D=\{x\in C[a,b]:\quad
 \int\limits_{a}^{b}|x(t)-1|dt\geq 1\}$$ is closed in $(C[a,b],d)$.
b)
Give an example to show that $d$ and $\rho$ are not equivalent. ($d$,
$\rho$ are equivalent if every subset $A$ of $C[a,b]$ is open in
$(C[a,b], d)$ if and only if $A$ is open in $(C[a,b], \rho))$

I already did part a). For part b) I currently can't find any example to show $d$ and $\rho$ are not equivalent. I would be very appreciated if someone could give me an example for part b). Thanks in advance!

Show by example that one of the unit balls is not contained in any ball of the other.

I don't get your point much

Show that the unit ball with $d$ is not open in $\rho$.

@copper.hat how to show the unit ball with $d$ is not open in$\rho$? Could you explain? Thanks

Show that the $d$ unit ball contains no $\rho$ open ball.

Hints
To prove that $\ \tau_1\ $ is stronger than $\ \tau_2\ $ you have to prove two things:

Every member of $\ \tau_2\ $ is in $\ \tau_1\ ;$ and
There's a member of $\ \tau_1\ $ which isn't in $\ \tau_2\ .$

You can prove the first (which I'm guessing you've already done) by using the inequality $\ \rho(x,y)\le (b-a)d(x,y)\ .$
As copper hat indicates in a comment, however, the open unit ball, $\ B_{\tau_1}(0,1)\ ,$ with respect to $\ \tau_1\ $ is not open with respect to $\ \tau_2\ ,$ and therefore constitutes an example of a member of $\ \tau_1\ $ which isn't in $\ \tau_2\ .$ To prove that $\ B_{\tau_1}(0,1)\not\in\tau_2\ ,$ show that every $\ \tau_2$-neighbourhood of $\ 0\ $ contains elements of $\ C[a,b]\ $ that aren't in $\ B_{\tau_1}(0,1) .$ This follows from the fact that for any $\ \epsilon>0\ $ there exists $\ x\in C[a,b]\ $ with $\ \rho(0,x)<\epsilon\ $ and $\ d(0,x)>1\ .$
Take
$$
x(t)=\cases{\frac{8(t-a)}{\epsilon}&for $\ a\le t\le a+\frac{\epsilon}{4}$\\
4-\frac{8(a-t)}{\epsilon}&for $\ a+\frac{\epsilon}{4}\le t\le a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$\\
0&for $\ a+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le t\le b\ ,$}
$$
for instance (where $\ \epsilon\le 2(b-a)\ $), when $\ \rho(0,x)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}\ $ but $\ d(0,x)=2\ .$

$\tau_1$ is stronger than $\tau_2$ if every member of $\tau_2$ is in $\tau_1$. Your first dot is wrong, I'm afraid

As was the second dot point.  It seems that I must have swapped which of the topologies was I supposing to be the stronger and the weaker just after I wrote the first sentence.  Thank you for picking it up.

I still can't prove the unit ball with $d$ is not open in $\rho$ though.

I've now added an example of an $\ x\ $ in $\ C[a,b]\ $ such that $\ \rho(0,x)<\epsilon\ $ but $\ d(0,x)=2\ .$
